# how can access the database of wikipedia by using C#?

Tags: c#

i want to access the database of Wikipedia to get the information of any thing  by using C#

Comment: similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627594/is-there-a-wikipedia-api

Comment: If you're looking into simply retrieving pages use: `HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.wikipedia.org/").GetResponse();`

Answer (score 4):

You can't access Wikipedia database (mysql probably) directly but you can use the Wikipedi API (actually MediaWiki API) to access information on Wikipedia.

More info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php

MediaWiki API is quite self explanatory and here: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API

You can simply retrieve the contents of any wikipedia page using httpwebrequest as posted here: [How to access wikipedia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560167/how-to-access-wikipedia)

Also using SPARQL to retrieve Wikipedia structured data seems to be an interesting and useful idea as in here: http://www.kozlenko.info/blog/2010/07/20/executing-sparql-query-on-wikipedia-in-net/

Answer (score 1):

Use the MediaWiki API

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Wikipedia API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use LINQPad with Wikipedia API